# Get index of DataFrame row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how to get back 10 from `df.iloc[10]` where `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(1,12)})`?
I tried df.index but it returns a weird np.array which doesn't contain anything close to 10.

Comment: Can you add small data sample and expected ouput?

Answer (score 0):

With `df.iloc` or `df.loc`, you obtain a series that corresponds to the columns of a given row in the dataframe:

```
>>> df
   foo
a   44
b   34
c   65
>>> df.iloc[1]
foo    34
Name: b, dtype: int64
>>> df.index[1]
'b'
>>> df.loc['b']
foo    34
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

You can see that the index of this second row, here `b`, is kept as the name of the series. Hence we can use it to find the position in the index:

```
>>> ser = df.iloc[1]
>>> df.index.get_indexer([ser.name])[0]
1
```

Note that [`Index.get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) only works with arrays, hence the need to get the first element of the answer.

Alternately you can always convert the index to a list and use `list.index` to find the element position, but this will likely be much slower:

```
>>> df.index.to_list().index(ser.name)
1
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, your answer led me to a more simple form. I don't completely understand why it works but it does `df.iloc[10].name == 10`

Comment: thanks again, I agree your answer means more common case than mine. On the other hand I'd expect a simple property to get int position of a row but alas it's not simple.

Comment: @bulklodd Yeah, but the row is taken as a separate object out of context, what if you modify the dataframe after accessing it, or add it to another dataframe? It gets compllicated.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution if the index matches the row numbers is `df.iloc[10].name` which returns `10`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is clear given the question. It does confuse `.iloc` and `.loc` however, so it will only work when the index matches the row numbers exactly.